# Mule: how to consume a service from a remote client

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, mule, endpoint

I have been following this tutorial which is really great to consume wb services from WSDL http://training.middlewareschool.com/mule/consuming-wsdl-first-service/. 
I have been trying to do a similar approach by generating a client web service in Eclipse using CXF and publishing the web service in Mule. My question is: if I configure for the client and mule application to have the same endpoint (for example: localhost:8082/ipsoap/test), how can I have the web service work the same way as with the tutorial. 
Meaning if I test sending a request to mule from the client (in eclipse) I should receive the right response from mule. Thank you in advance for your time.

So in short:

1-I generated a client app in eclipse using the wsdl in the following link in the tutorial: http://ws.cdyne.com/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx?wsdl

2- As a start in Mule, I added an http connector and a logger and changed the endpoint path in eclipse to the one I set on the HTTP connector on Mule. Thus, I can see that there is a payload when I am sending a request to Mule from the client in Eclipse.

3- I need to have an application, namely my client app in eclipse, consume a published service in Mule. Now I think this is achieved using the CXF component but I still fail to make it work. In fact, I wonder if this is one valid way of using Mule since I couldn't find any tutorial about what I am trying to achieve.

So here is how I test it:
[image]

I used the same endpoint I used in Mule and receive the following log:

```
> INFO  2014-07-07 13:19:46,124
> [[soapservice].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]
> org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: message transformation
> <soapenv:Envelope
> xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
> xmlns:q0="http://ws.cdyne.com/"
> xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
> <soapenv:Body>
>     <q0:ResolveIP>
>       <q0:ipAddress>173.194.36.39</q0:ipAddress>
>       <q0:licenseKey/>
>     </q0:ResolveIP>   </soapenv:Body> </soapenv:Envelope>
> 
> ERROR 2014-07-07 13:19:46,134
> [[soapservice].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02]
> org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
> ******************************************************************************** Message               : wrong number of arguments. Failed to route
> event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.
> Message payload is of type: String Code                  :
> MULE_ERROR--2
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
> 1. wrong number of arguments (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException)   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl:-2 (null)
> 2. wrong number of arguments. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of
> type: String (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)  
> org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150
> (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong
> number of arguments   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

As you can see the soap request can be seen but it is not consumed at the level of the CXF component. Here is my mule code:

```
<flow name="SoapService" doc:name="SoapService">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" path="test/cap.asmx" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
        <logger message="message transformation #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <flow-ref name="RequestResponse" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="after posting #[message.payload]"/>
        <mulexml:object-to-xml-transformer doc:name="Object to XML"/>
    </flow>
    <flow name="RequestResponse" doc:name="RequestResponse">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="ResolveIP" clientClass="pck.IP2Geo" port="IP2GeoSoap" wsdlLocation="file:/C:/Users/12204-hajjam1/workspace/ipgo/src/ipgeo.wsdl" doc:name="soap 2"/>
        <logger message="before posting #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" address="http://localhost:10387/ip2geo/ip2geo.asmx" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    </flow>
```

Also if I add a set payload with the ip #[{'173.194.36.39',''}] (the second argument can be left empty) before the cxf component it returns a an empty  element. Yet, the response should be something like this:

```
<pck.IPInformation>
<city>Mountain View</city>
<stateProvince>CA</stateProvince>
<country>United States</country>
<organization/>
<latitude>37.4192</latitude>
<longitude>-122.0574</longitude>
<areaCode>0</areaCode>
<timeZone/>
<hasDaylightSavings>false</hasDaylightSavings>
<certainty>90</certainty>
<regionName/>
<countryCode>US</countryCode>
</pck.IPInformation>
```

Thus, my problem is with the consumption and retrieval of the response.
I apologize for the length but I have been struggling with this and haven't found a solution online. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I can't understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you possibly extend/rephrase your question?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have edited my question. I hope it's fine this way otherwise I can make it clearer.

Comment: Any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an instance of the message class that as been generated for the `ResolveIP` method from the WSDL and use it as the message payload before the `cxf:jaxws-client` element.

Comment: Indeed, I tried setting the payload as suggested and it s working. Yet I managed to find my problem by removing the cxf client and simply leaving an HTTP outbound with the location address of the WSDL and now it returns the right response. Thus the problem was with having two clients one in eclipse and one in mule. Thank you for your answer !